# "but that occasionally"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Biologists have found that all tadpoles of that species begin life as
>   omnivores, feeding mainly on organic debris in their soon-to-be-dry
>   pool in the desert, **but that occasionally** one tadpole eats another or
>   eats a freshwater shrimp.

I don't understand this sentence because of the bold part. Can I just consider "**but that occasionally**" as "**and**" so  the whole sentence means, *tadpoles mainly feed on organic debris and they also feed on each other or freshwater shrimp*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**but that** has the meaning of **except** ([1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/but_that)).

In your paragraph, it basically means

> tadpoles feed mainly on organic derbis in their soon-to-be-dry pool in the desert, **except occasionally** one tadpole eats another or eats a freshwater shrimp.

Comment: The dictionary that you linked gives me this sentence: "She would have screamed, but that her cry would have called her masters".

Comment: In this case, does "but that" has a meaning as "if it does not happen"?  If I just directly replace "but that" with "except", the whole sentence sounds awkward. So my question is, does "but that" has two meanings-1.except  2.if not  ?

Comment: @user198952 it surely doesn't mean "if not" in your sentence, but you could say so